# Extracting table names from multiple strings using Perl regex

Tags: regex, perl

I want to extract all of the table names from this partial SQL query. Please note that I'm reading this line by line, not as one string:

```
from DS_RAN_CORID t1, NAMON_GNS t4, NA_VAL_ROL t6, A_TI_G_V t7, PTSM_TCR t2
left outer join T_TR_COR_LAG t3
on  t2.inp_seq = t3.inp_seq and t3.ti_number = t2.ti_number
left outer join OUT_TR_COR t5
on  t2.inp_seq=t5.inp_seq and t5.ti_number=t2.ti_number
where t1.inp_seq = t2.inp_seq and t2.ti_number = t6.interval_number and
      t1.ti_grp = t7.dm_group and t2.ti_number = t7.interval_number;
```

The tables i need to extract: `DS_RAN_CORID/ NAMON_GNS/ NA_VAL_ROL/ A_TI_G_V/ PTSM_TCR/ T_TR_COR_LAG/ OUT_TR_COR/`

I tried this:

1. Match the `t1.`, `t2.` etc., for any letter and any digit:

   `$string=~m/(\S).\d/gi;`
2. Assuming that my code is correct, I need to compare the `t1.` with `TABLE_NAME t1` and extract the table name with something like this:

   `$string=~m/\w+\s+(S)\d/gi;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought [SQL::Parser](https://metacpan.org/pod/SQL::Parser) might help, but it chokes on the SQL. I am leaving this here as a reference point:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use SQL::Parser;

my $sql = <<SQL;
select *
from DS_RAN_CORID t1, NAMON_GNS t4, NA_VAL_ROL t6, A_TI_G_V t7, PTSM_TCR t2
left outer join T_TR_COR_LAG t3
on  t2.inp_seq = t3.inp_seq and t3.ti_number = t2.ti_number
left outer join OUT_TR_COR t5
on  t2.inp_seq=t5.inp_seq and t5.ti_number=t2.ti_number
where t1.inp_seq = t2.inp_seq and t2.ti_number = t6.interval_number and
      t1.ti_grp = t7.dm_group and t2.ti_number = t7.interval_number;
SQL

my $parser = SQL::Parser->new;
$parser->dialect('MySQL');

die unless $parser->parse( $sql );

print "$_\n" for @{ $parser->structure->{table_names} };
```

As for using regexes, I am going to note that all table names seem to consist of upper case ASCII and underscore:

```
my (%tables) = reverse ($sql =~ /([A-Z][A-Z_]+) \s+ (t[1-9])/gx);
print Dump \%tables;
```

```
---
t1: DS_RAN_CORID
t2: PTSM_TCR
t3: T_TR_COR_LAG
t4: NAMON_GNS
t5: OUT_TR_COR
t6: NA_VAL_ROL
t7: A_TI_G_V
```

Comment: You grabbed too many tables. Some of those are from the JOIN and not just from the FROM clause.

Comment: Using the module SQL:Parser looks so easy , i am new to perl and i never used a module before .Can you explain this : %tables , why use a hash and not an @array ? And why use revers () ?

Comment: @CDahn I need the table after JOIN too , JOIN is after the FROM , i need all the tables matching this patter NAME_OF_THE_TABLE tn , where n is at least 1.

Comment: @Cristi.Fatu: Please amend your question to say so. It says exactly the opposite of that at present.